# Commit Offsets to Kafka on Spark Executors

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I am getting events from Kafka, enriching/filtering/transforming them on Spark and then storing them in ES. I am committing back the offsets to Kafka

I have two questions/problems:

**(1) My current Spark job is VERY slow**

I have 50 partitions for a topic and 20 executors. Each executor has 2 cores and 4g of memory each. My driver has 8g of memory. I am consuming 1000 events/partition/second and my batch interval is 10 seconds. This means, I am consuming 500000 events in 10 seconds

My ES cluster is as follows:

20 shards / index

3 master instances c5.xlarge.elasticsearch

12 instances m4.xlarge.elasticsearch

disk / node = 1024 GB so 12 TB in total

And I am getting huge scheduling and processing delays

**(2) How can I commit offsets on executors?**

Currently, I enrich/transform/filter my events on executors and then send everything to ES using **BulkRequest**. It's a synchronous process. If I get positive feedback, I send the offset list to driver. If not, I send back an empty list. On the driver, I commit offsets to Kafka. I believe, there should be a way, where I can commit offsets on executors but I don't know how to pass kafka Stream to executors:

```
((CanCommitOffsets) kafkaStream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges, this::onComplete);
```

This is the code for committing offsets to Kafka which requires Kafka Stream

Here is my overall code:

```
 kafkaStream.foreachRDD( // kafka topic
                rdd -> { // runs on driver
                    rdd.cache();
                    String batchIdentifier =
                            Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));

                    LOGGER.info("@@ [" + batchIdentifier + "] Starting batch ...");

                    Instant batchStart = Instant.now();

                    List<OffsetRange> offsetsToCommit =
                            rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex( // kafka partition
                                    (index, eventsIterator) -> { // runs on worker

                                        OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

                                        LOGGER.info(
                                                "@@ Consuming " + offsetRanges[index].count() + " events" + " partition: " + index
                                        );

                                        if (!eventsIterator.hasNext()) {
                                            return Collections.emptyIterator();
                                        }

                                        // get single ES documents
                                        List<SingleEventBaseDocument> eventList = getSingleEventBaseDocuments(eventsIterator);

                                        // build request wrappers
                                        List<InsertRequestWrapper> requestWrapperList = getRequestsToInsert(eventList, offsetRanges[index]);

                                        LOGGER.info(
                                                "@@ Processed " + offsetRanges[index].count() + " events" + " partition: " + index + " list size: " + eventList.size()
                                        );

                                        BulkResponse bulkItemResponses = elasticSearchRepository.addElasticSearchDocumentsSync(requestWrapperList);

                                        if (!bulkItemResponses.hasFailures()) {
                                            return Arrays.asList(offsetRanges).iterator();
                                        }

                                        elasticSearchRepository.close();
                                        return Collections.emptyIterator();
                                    },
                                    true
                            ).collect();

                    LOGGER.info(
                            "@@ [" + batchIdentifier + "] Collected all offsets in " + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - batchStart.toEpochMilli()) + "ms"
                    );

                    OffsetRange[] offsets = new OffsetRange[offsetsToCommit.size()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < offsets.length ; i++) {
                        offsets[i] = offsetsToCommit.get(i);
                    }

                    try {
                        offsetManagementMapper.commit(offsets);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // ignore
                    }

                    LOGGER.info(
                            "@@ [" + batchIdentifier + "] Finished batch of " + offsetsToCommit.size() + " messages " +
                                    "in " + (Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - batchStart.toEpochMilli()) + "ms"
                    );
                    rdd.unpersist();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the offset logic above the rdd loop ... I am using below template for better offset handling and performance

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));



        kafkaStream.foreachRDD( kafkaStreamRDD -> {
            //fetch kafka offsets for manually commiting it later
            OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) kafkaStreamRDD.rdd()).offsetRanges();

            //filter unwanted data
            kafkaStreamRDD.filter(
                    new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> kafkaRecord) throws Exception {
                    if(kafkaRecord!=null) {
                        if(!StringUtils.isAnyBlank(kafkaRecord.key() , kafkaRecord.value())) {
                            return Boolean.TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                    return Boolean.FALSE;
                }
            }).foreachPartition( kafkaRecords -> {

                // init connections here

                while(kafkaRecords.hasNext()) {
                    ConsumerRecord<String, String> kafkaConsumerRecord = kafkaRecords.next();
                    // work here
                }

            });
            //commit offsets
            ((CanCommitOffsets) kafkaStream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have a question though. The reason why I'm collecting is because I need to know which executor was able to store events in ES properly. I might be wrong, but if I follow your approach, then I'd be committing offsets without checking if the executors have properly stored data or not

Comment: you can create some custom exceptions because which your task will fail if it didn't persist the data to ES.  In case of failure you spark will retry for configured number of times. Only then your offsets will be committed. Regarding storing offsets at executor level you might have to use some persistence layer. Please let me know if you have a better approach here.

Comment: I am okay with storing offsets on the driver, I just don't know how to tell the driver that everything is stored in ES. And if I do this on driver then I'd have to collect all the results from executors to driver